# Change browser type and version using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, user-agent

I am using the code below to change my user agent using the Selenium Webdriver. However, I can see that Google analytics can easily detect my browser and even its version every time (Firefox 54.0 in this case). Tried it with Chromedriver as well. Same result.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

useragent = ua.random

#Chrome
'''
opts.add_argument('"'+useragent+'"')
driver =  webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
'''

#Firefox
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", useragent)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("www.mywebsite.com")
```

How can I change the user agent properly?

Comment: Have you tried this using requests module?

Comment: No. But, I will need Selenium in my case.. btw, have you tested the `requests` with google analytics?

Comment: Nope didn't try. That's why I was asking if you did instead of putting it up in the answers.

Comment: would be interesting if they behave differently. anyway, i'd prefere an answer for selenium, if any

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Considering your aim is to change the **`User Agent`** using the **`Selenium Webdriver`**, you can use the code block below to access a website every time with a random **`User Agent`** using **`FirefoxProfile`**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
useragent = UserAgent()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", useragent.random)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.whatsmyua.info/")
```

### Observation

On three different runs the `User Agents` generated were:

1. **`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20130331 Firefox/21.0`**
2. **`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36`**
3. **`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko`**

Let me know if this Answers your Question.